# Blazor - Writing text to background

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am trying to write text to the background of a blazor application.

I want it to show all my method calls in the background (so it looks techy!)

Does anyone know the best way to do this? I have researched but found nothing as of yet.

Comment: A blazor application is UI-side not much different from normal HTML, so you could try to find out the HTML-way what you are trying to achieve (as I don't understand right now, what you are acutally want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the HTML/CSS side, it should be something along these lines:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <style>
    #content{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0%;
      left: 0%;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: black;
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    
    #background{
        color: darkgray;
    }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
        This is my<br/>
        background<br/>
        content ...<br />
    </div>  
    <div id="content">
        This is my overlay content.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Two content blocks are created with the div tags: one for the foreground and one for the background. JavaScript can then be used to animate/adjust the background content accordingly to get your required effect.